# How to access a site on another machine in the same domain programmatically?

Tags: 2010, domain, spsite

I have a site on DOMAIN\PC1 with url `http://site1`. I can access it by using following code (code is running on DOMAIN\PC1):

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site1"))
{

}
```

Also there is a site with url `http://site2` on machine DOMAIN\PC2 in the same domain.
The code presented below fails (code is also running on DOMAIN\PC1):

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site2"))
{

}
```

How to access `http://site2` on DOMAIN\PC2 programmatically by code run on DOMAIN\PC1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these sites in the same Farm? The code you have above will only be able to access SPSite object that runs on the same Farm as where you are in now. In other words, you cannot Access sites from a different farm.

If you really need to access some data, then you will have to call the Web Services on `"http://site2"`